# Use a jq range variable to feed into a new jq filter

Tags: variables, pipeline, jq

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "vertices": [
        {
         "id": 71597,
          "ns": "ca",
          "alias": "polarized"
        },
        {
          "id": 129748,
          "ns": "av",
          "name": "Polarized"
        },
        {
          "id": 129898,
          "ns": "av",
          "name": "False"
        }
    ],
    "edgeGroups": {
        "hasAttributeValue": [
            [
              0,
              1
            ],
            [
              0,
              2
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

The various entries in `.vertices` are related by their array index. So in this case, the first vertex (id: 71597 - with an array index of 0) has attribute values 129748 and 129898 (with array indices 1 and two respectively).

I can get the array index for the attribute I'm searching for with the following jq filter:

`.vertices | range(0;length) as $i | select(.[$i].alias=="polarized" and .[$i].ns=="ca") | $i`

That returns an $i value of 0, since the object with alias "polarized" is the first item in the array. You can try it out here on jq play:

https://jqplay.org/s/DsHYi7ixyn

Now I want to **use that $i value** in a different filter, so instead of outputting 0 it outputs something like the result of this:

`.edgeGroups.hasAttributeValue[] | select(.[0] == 0)`

I've tried using the pipe operator like this but it just gives me an error:

`.vertices | range(0;length) as $i | select(.[$i].alias=="polarized" and .[$i].ns=="ca") | .edgeGroups.hasAttributeValue[] | select(.[0] == $i)`

If I could understand how to use the $i in a chained filter, I think I could solve my main goal, which is to chain several filters together so that I can get all the items associated with the 71597 object - i.e.

```
        {
          "id": 129748,
          "ns": "av",
          "name": "Polarized"
        },
        {
          "id": 129898,
          "ns": "av",
          "name": "False"
        }
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but the question is very unclear.  You show what the result should be, but the explanation in terms of  .edgeGroups seems completely unrelated.  Please clarify. By the way, you might be able to solve your problem if you focus on the way data flows through the pipeline you create.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, but the way that items are related in edgeGroups is relevant. Basically, I want to feed the value $i from the first filter (which is the array index in edgeGroups.hasAttributeValue) in the next jq filter: .edgeGroups.hasAttributeValue[] | select(.[0] == i) <-- use $i here. Does that explain it better?

Comment: That's what I guessed, as you'll see in the posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jq filter could be fixed with a couple of parentheses:

```
(.vertices
 | range(0;length) as $i
 | select(.[$i].alias=="polarized" and .[$i].ns=="ca")
 | $i) as $i
| .edgeGroups.hasAttributeValue[]
| select(.[0] == $i)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. And I was able to continue this pattern to get the details of the items with ns: av, which was my ultimate goal by doing: (.vertices  | range(0;length) as $i  | select(.[$i].alias=="polarized" and .[$i].ns=="ca")  | $i) as $i | (.edgeGroups.hasAttributeValue[] | select(.[0] == $i)[1]) as $j| .vertices[$j]